# Asp.net how to solve the error

Tags: asp.net

Im designing my web page, in that i have typed in the book id and typed Nameofthebook. and then click the button the stack of book are available is go to another page and then not available is display the error message is book is not available My project (Library management system)

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Bookcheck : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string constr = null;
        constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["librarymanagementconnetionstring"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(constr);
        cnn.Open();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT*FROM BOOKREGISTRATIONDETAILS WHERE bookId='" + txtid.Text.Trim() + "'AND Nameofbook='" + txtnb.Text.Trim() + "'", constr);
        da.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            Response.Redirect("Issueofbook.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            Msg.Text = "NO book available";
            Msg.Visible = true;
        }
    }       
}
```

Error:
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Which line gives the error? Is it `ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count`? Something is clearly unset but without the line I'd only be guessing.

Comment: where exactly does the error occur?

Comment: If you are using VS, then there is a feature called `Debugging`. You can try that. You get object ref error when you are trying to use some object whose value is `null`

Comment: My guess would be `constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[...]`, but as you say, it's a guess :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that it's the line

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
```

that giving the error.

If your `DataSet` has no tables then `ds.Tables` could be null.

If that's a possibility then you need to code for that.

If there are no rows `ds.Tables[0].Rows` won't be null and your test should work.

Comment: Table with no rows will have Rows collection with 0 count.

Answer (score 5):

I noticed that in **librarymanagementconnetionstring**, *connection* is spelled incorrectly. Is this the correct entry in your web.config for the connection string?

Comment: Well spotted, I missed that. Upon reflection that's probably more likely than my suggestion.

Comment: Good catch, that's the most likely cause for the error. Sorry @Chris noticed your comment only after posting my own! :-/

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
```

to

```
if(ds.HasRows)
```